# How do I increase swap memory in debian?

Tags: debian, swap

how to increase swap memory in debian?

Comment: Umm...doesn't this belong on SU?

Answer (score 24):

In a pinch, you can create a new swap partition or file.

For a partition:

1. Format the new partition with `mkswap /dev/sdx1`
2. Add the new swap partition to /etc/fstab.
3. Run `swapon -a` to activate the new swap.

To add a swap file:

1. Create the file. This command creates a 1 gigabyte file: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1000`
2. Format the swap file: `mkswap /swap`
3. Add the new swap file to /etc/fstab: `/swap swap swap defaults 0 0`
4. Run `swapon -a` to activate the new swap.

Comment: Btw. you will have to run `swapon` with `sudo`, otherwise you might get `command not found`.

Answer (score 11):

Run the following commands

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=512k count=1024
mkswap /swap
chmod 0600 /swap
swapon /swap
```

you will also have to add this line to /etc/fstab

```
/swap swap swap defaults 0 0
```

You can run `free -m` to find the swap space used in megabytes before and after the allocation of swap space.

Answer (score 1):

Good info on several ways to increase/change swap partition size here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq. Follow the steps mentioned in section: `How do I add more swap?`

This needs a few changes.

1. You need to do `swapoff -a` after you update the /etc/fstab with the new swap partition info. Without this, after you run `swapoff` at a later stage, it will show both partitions.
2. Even if you use hibernation, you may not need to add the new swap's UUID in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in /etc/default/grub file.

The other steps steps are fine and works.